# an online video screenshot with php script

Tags: php, youtube, screenshot

Can anyone recommend me a online video screenshot with php script?
I tried webscreencapture, iecapt, html2png. but just get a white screen. Is there any way to write a php code that can set time delay and catch the online video screenshot?

Comment: I'd like to know how PHP could play a YouTube video to begin with, it being server side and not able to run Flash and all...

Comment: @deceze, technically there's [the Ming extension](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/book.ming.php), but it has only very basic support for understanding video content in Flash, and is pretty funky to begin with.

Comment: @Charles Ming allows you to *create* Flash content, but as far as I can tell it can't *play* any Flash content...

Comment: @deceze, you seem to be correct.

Comment: I have built a simple API to get frames from youtube videos: https://rapidapi.com/abyesilyurt/api/youtube-screenshot1/details. It does not require any server side changes, just an http request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install ffmpeg module server side if you are using linux server. http://www.ffmpeg.org/

Comment: hi ,how to write a simple php code that can execute ffmpeg? including url, delay time and image save path? Thanks.

Comment: Hi , first you need to install ffmpeg-php module , read this for installations http://setahost.com/centos-5-ffmpeg-installation/

Comment: Here is how to regarding ffmpeg-php http://vexxhost.com/blog/2007/05/20/how-to-convertencode-files-to-flv-using-ffmpeg-php/